# Creating (and saving to) an object with a random name

Tags: r

I have a function which I use repeatedly. One of the things it returns is a plot visualising effects of a model. I want the function to save the plot to an object, but I want the name of the object to have a random component to it. I use the function multiple times and don't want the plots to overwrite. But I could use the unique identifier in its name to reference it later for the writeup.

So I tried a few things, trying to save a simple object under a partially-random name. All of them  fail because I put a function left from the "<-" sign. I'm not going to give examples, because they are just very very wrong.

So I'd like to have something like:

```
NAME(randomNumber) <- "some plot"
```

Which, after running multiple times in a function (with the actual input on the right of course) would result in objects named randomly like

```
NAME104, NAME314, NAME235, etc.
```

Is this at all doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its doable.

Don't do it.

Make a LIST of objects. You can use the name as the key in the list. Example:

```
 plots = list()
 plots[["NAME104"]] = "some plot"
 plots[["NAMEXXX"]] = "some other plot"
```

Why? Because now it's easy to loop over the plots stored in the list. Its also easy to create the list in a loop in the first place, something like:

```
 for(i in 1:100){
   data = read.table(paste("data",i,".csv"))
   name = data$name[1] # get name from column in file
   plots[[name]] = plotthing(data)
 }
```

If you really really want to create a thing with a random name, use `assign`:

```
> assign(paste0("NAME",round(runif(1,1,1000))), "hello")
> ls(pattern="NAME*")
[1] "NAME11"  "NAME333" "NAME717" "NAME719"
```

But really *DONT* do that.

Comment: I buy your argument. So simple! Again, R allows you to achieve the same thing from so many different angles. SO many, it's confusing :)